# Debian ignores second multicast packet

Tags: linux, debian, udp, multicast

I have a home local network with several devices. One of the devices is sending multicast packets with information about some events (smart home). It works well - I've tried to launch Multicast Tester app on my Android phone, and I see all of packets which were sent by the smart home device.

Also I have a server with Gnu/Linux. It is based on old Samsung NC10. There is a little problem with multicast: when smart home device sends two multicast packets one by one quickly, the Gnu/Linux server receives only the first packet and ignores the second. To check it I am using `tcpdump dst port 9898 -X` and I see two packets on Android and only first on Gnu/Linux.

I also checked the router, but there is no specific settings for this server or multicasts. It looks like the problem is in Gnu/Linux settings.

I also tryed to check it with `watch -d "cat /proc/net/snmp | grep -w Udp"`:

```
# watch -d "cat /proc/net/snmp | grep -w Udp"

Every 2,0s: cat /proc/net/snmp | grep -w Udp                                                                                                                                                                                         BArtWell-Server: Tue Jan  7 15:36:38 2020

Udp: InDatagrams NoPorts InErrors OutDatagrams RcvbufErrors SndbufErrors InCsumErrors IgnoredMulti
Udp: 252376 567 385 163222 0 0 385 9288
```

I am confused with `IgnoredMulti` number, it looks great.

Example of packets:

```
IP 192.168.0.9.4321 > 224.0.0.50.9898: UDP: {"cmd":"report","model":"sensor_motion.aq2","sid":"158d0002b5d0ba","short_id":9406,"data":"{\"lux\":\"168\"}"}
IP 192.168.0.9.4321 > 224.0.0.50.9898: UDP: {"cmd":"report","model":"sensor_motion.aq2","sid":"158d0002b5d0ba","short_id":9406,"data":"{\"status\":\"motion\"}"}
```

ifconfig:

```
# ifconfig wlp2s0
wlp2s0: flags=4675<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,ALLMULTI,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::225:56ff:fe26:2379  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:25:56:26:23:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 634427  bytes 210441311 (200.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 394252  bytes 113622848 (108.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

How can I fix this problem? How can I force Gnu/Linux to not ignore the second multicast packet when it was sent quickly?

Comment: Are the 2 packets identical ? What are the flags set on the network interface ? Did you tried `ifconfig <your nic> allmulti` ? (see man 8 ifconfig).

Comment: Two questions:  Are the packets going over WiFi at all?  Have you been able to successfully capture both packets from another device connected to the same network in promiscuous mode?

Comment: @binarym Okay, now it looks better. I've called two commands `apt upgrade` and `ifconfig wlp2s0 allmulti` and now packets get ignored very rarely. But sometimes they are still ignored.

Comment: Do you get some log regarding packet loss in `dmesg` ? Also, `ifconfig` shows a counter of erroneous packets and drop packets ... can you see this counter getting incremented while loosing packets ?

Comment: @binarym did you meant `dmesg | grep multi`? Nothing interesting. About ifconfig counter - I update the question and add ifconfig output. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm, it looks strange. As I wrote before the situation looks good after update and enable allmulti. But now it get bad as it was before. The problem happens  quite often. I wasn't reboot it and don't changed any files. But the problem came back.

Comment: @Questionmark yes, they all going over WiFi. It also missing some packages from another device when I send it fast.

Comment: Have you checked if the WiFi power saving is enabled?  `iw dev wlp2s0 set power_save off`

Comment: @Questionmark This command show nothing. After this command situation looks better (I am not sure, it is hard to diagnose), but some packets still getting missed.